# Error: Failed building wheel for pythonnet

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, clr, python.net

I am trying to install pythonnet and i can't for some reason and it just gives me this error whenever i try to install it

```
pip3 install pythonnet
Collecting pythonnet
  Using cached pythonnet-2.5.2.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\0991t\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pythonnet) (2.20)
Building wheels for collected packages: pythonnet
  Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\0991t\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\0991t\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-u9mp60rw'
       cwd: C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\
  Complete output (80 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
  Currently running NuGet.exe 4.1.0.
  Updating NuGet.exe to 6.0.0.
  Update successful.
  Cannot find the specified version of msbuild: '14'
  MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.11.2.50704' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
  Restoring NuGet package NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.11.1.
  Restoring NuGet package NUnit.3.12.0.
  Restoring NuGet package System.ValueTuple.4.5.0.
  Restoring NuGet package UnmanagedExports.1.2.7.
  Adding package 'NUnit.3.12.0' to folder 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\packages'
  Adding package 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.11.1' to folder 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\packages'
  Adding package 'UnmanagedExports.1.2.7' to folder 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\packages'
  Adding package 'System.ValueTuple.4.5.0' to folder 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\packages'
  Added package 'UnmanagedExports.1.2.7' to folder 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\packages'
  Added package 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.11.1' to folder 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\packages'
  Added package 'System.ValueTuple.4.5.0' to folder 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\packages'
  Added package 'NUnit.3.12.0' to folder 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\packages'

  NuGet Config files used:
      C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
      C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

  Feeds used:
      C:\Users\0991t\.nuget\packages\
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

  Installed:
      4 package(s) to packages.config projects
  Microsoft (R) Manifest Tool

  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

  All rights reserved.

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\setup.py", line 630, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 155, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\setup.py", line 612, in run
      return bdist_wheel.bdist_wheel.run(self)
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\setup.py", line 345, in build_extension
      manifest = self._get_manifest(dest_dir)
    File "C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\setup.py", line 389, in _get_manifest
      subprocess.check_call(" ".join(cmd), shell=False)
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\mt.exe -inputresource:"C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe" -out:"C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\app.manifest"' returned non-zero exit status 31.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonnet
  Running setup.py clean for pythonnet
Failed to build pythonnet
Installing collected packages: pythonnet
    Running setup.py install for pythonnet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\0991t\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\0991t\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-l9hhufpc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\pythonnet'
         cwd: C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\0991t\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\0991t\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-oqtzzy7u\\pythonnet_3e469843a44f4517b9f84bc86e79df93\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-l9hhufpc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\0991t\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\pythonnet' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have tried updating setuptools, pip, and wheel. I have tried a lot of things but i just can't wrap my head around why it is causing this error. I am using the latest pip version and using the latest python version. Im also using the latest setuptools version and the latest wheel version. Sorry i am trying to make my question not mostly code so i can actually post it lol.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you @Thomas.

I had the same issue, this solved my problem and install successfully.

Due to pythonnet version mismatch python 3.10.1 reported this error.

Go to: https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/

Then Follow these steps:

1. Open the official website ：pythonnet.
2. Click on the "Download files".
3. Then download "pythonnet-2.5.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl" (for 64-bit python version)
4. Modify file name like this:
   Before: pythonnet-2.5.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
   After: pythonnet-2.5.2-cp310-none-any.whl
5. And now try to install like: pip install path of the file
   ex: pip install C:\users\user5\desktop\pythonnet-2.5.2-cp310-none-any.whl

I hope this help you. All the best.

Original post: https://www.codestudyblog.com/cs2112pyc/1221121223.html